# Will Monero have unconfirmed transactions problems like bitcoin?

Tags: transaction-confirmation

Recently there has been many unconfirmed transactions with bitcoin resulting in transactions taking a lot of time to process (12 hours+). I was wondering if Monero would have the same problem in the future if there were many transactions? Would it have delayed transactions like bitcoin? Are there any solutions to deal with it that is in work or could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin has a backlog because there's only so many transactions that can fit into their 1mb blocks.

Monero has an adaptive blocksize limit so in general it doesn't suffer from this problem.  There can, however, be periods where there is a backlog because the blocksize limit isn't increasing rapidly enough.

If a miner mines a block that is too large, compared to recent blocks, it will forfeit the blockreward.  If however the transaction backlog becomes large enough a rational miner will mine a big block anyway, because a large block full of fee-paying transaction can net more than the blockreward.